# The joint distribution of $(X^2, Y^2)$ under bivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $(X_1, Y_1),..., (X_n, Y_n)$ be a random sample of size $n \geq 2$ from $(X,Y) \sim N_2 (0,0,1,1,\rho)$. Compute the joint distribution of $(X^2, Y^2)$.

I know how to compute the covariance of $(X^2, Y^2)$, which is $1 + 2 \rho^2$. But I don't know how to get the joint distribution of $(X^2, Y^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us denote $(U,V) = (X^2, V^2)$, we will determine de density function $f_{U,V}(u,v)$  for $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Make the change of variable by using the Jacobian method (as in this [note](https://www.math.utah.edu/lectures/math2210/25PostNotes.pdf)), the Jacobian matrix is:

$$J(u,v) =\left| \matrix{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}   }  \right| = \left| \matrix{2x&0 \\ 0&2y  }  \right| = 4xy =4\sqrt{uv}$$

Then
$$\begin{align}
f_{U,V}(u,v) &= f_{X,Y}(x,y)J(u,v)\\ &= 4\sqrt{uv} \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\cdot\exp{\left(-\frac{x^2-2\rho xy + y^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}  \right)}\\
&=4\sqrt{uv} \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\cdot\exp{\left(-\frac{u-2\rho \sqrt{uv} + v}{2(1-\rho^2)}  \right)} \hspace{1cm} \forall u,v\in \mathbb{R}^+ \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

By consequence, the distribution of $(U,V)$ is defined by the function $f$ in $(1)$.

Comment: @markleeds it is the density function of a bivariate normal disitribution with correlation $\rho$, you can find it [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html)

Comment: Thanks NN2. I deleted my question by accident. But that made sense.

Comment: for future readers, my question was where did the exponent of exp come from.

Comment: I don't think your Jacobian is correct. I think it should be the reciprocal

Comment: @Jackie why do you think so? For information, the notation in the answer follows your notation (in the question) and is not the one in the note I mentionned

Comment: @NN2 I am pretty sure that your Jacobian is wrong. Each element in the Jacobian should be $\frac{dx}{du}, \frac{dx}{dv}$, not the opposite.

Comment: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/23/23.1

Comment: @Jackie Look as the note that I mentionned and remind that $(u,v)\leftrightarrow (x,y)$. Besides, the two methods (the one you mentionned and mine) are equivalent and must obtain the same result.

Comment: @NN2 But our result is different. That's weird. My result has the same density as yours except I have $\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{uv}}$. You have $4 \sqrt{uv}$.

Comment: By the way, what's the final density? Is it a well-known named distribution?

Comment: the vector $(X^2,Y^2)$ follows the joint distribution of 2 correlated Central Chi-Square variables with $N=1$ degree of freedom. I doubt this distribution has a special name: for example, in Marvin Simon's _"Probability Distributions Involving Gaussian Random Variables: A Handbook for Engineers, Scientists and Mathematicians"_ (Springer, 2002), Section 2.D, the distribution is presented for general $N$, but without a special name. Note that the handbook does assume only correlation between corresponding entries of Gaussian vectors, but in this case with scalar variables, that checks out.